# Can not find line break setting after opening curly brace in resharper

Tags: resharper

When I create a new javascript constructor I want to do this:

```
var PersonViewModel = function(){};
```

Then I press return after the semicolon and get this:

```
var PersonViewModel = function()
{
};
```

But what I want is this:

```
var PersonViewModel = function()
{
   // so I can immediately continue writing code here
};
```

I want that line break after the opening curly brace.

I can not find the settings in the javascript options, anyone knows please?

Comment: Why don't you just place the cursor between the braces and then press enter?

Comment: this would work, but then the semicolon is missing and I do not want to extra go down after the closing curly brace and set that semicolon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReSharper tries very hard not to mess with user typing (at least when it is correct). It can help you not to touch very much, but if you want to type something fully, it tries to allow you to do it. But the feature that you want breaks this principle: when user would type to function statement side-by-side, the second one would be inside the first one instead.

What I suggest instead is just typing `...function(){` and pressing Enter. ReSharper would add `}` for you automatically, so you can just continue to write function body. You would get syntactically correct code, because `;` could be omitted in JavaScript. ReSharper would highlight missing `;` anyway and would suggest to add all missing `;` in the whole file. Just use this feature from time to time to make your code beautiful.

Comment: I marked this as solution as best answer although it does not help me. When I type the "{" the "}" is created automatically. And pressing return between them gets me nothing as the semicolon is not added. Yes Resharper can add those but these are some extra clicks... I do not understand why resharper can not directly add the semicolon after a function without asking me...

Comment: @Elisa I guess that's because there should be a complex logic in deciding when to add ';' after '}', but too few developers would appreciate that (not everybody loves `;` after `}`). Maybe I'm wrong here, so I added http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-356670 to see how many people would vote for it.